# Content-by-user: two tables with columns of the same name or join?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, join

The title pretty much says it all. I have users posting content, and I would like to attach the user ID that is in the users table to the posts. Should I add a userid column in the posts table, should I join via the DB language, or should I use the scripting language to poll each table?  If I should join, what kind of join should I do?

Sample content would look like this: "The teddy bears at my store are softer than the teddy goats, but the teddy goats are more lovable." - Posted by James Teddyman at 3:36 PM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very often-used concept in situation like this is by having a users table and a post table, linking them together with a unique identifier. This identifier can be anything - a serialized id, a user name, mail address, etc - as long as it's unique. Linking is done using a foreign key constraint. Exactly how this is achieved in MySQL I do not know, but in Postgres it's done like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
  content text,
  user_id integer REFERENCES users(id) NOT NULL
);
```

The tables are then merged using a join. This can be done in several ways, but here is a cross join after insertion of some values to play with:

```
@> INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('James');
@> INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('Jones');
@> INSERT INTO posts (content, user_id) VALUES ('Hello from James.', 1);
@> INSERT INTO posts (content, user_id) VALUES ('Greetings from Jones.', 2);
@> SELECT U.id AS user_id, U.name, P.content \
   FROM users U, posts P \
   WHERE U.id = P.user_id;

 user_id | name  |        content
---------+-------+-----------------------
       1 | James | Hello from James.
       2 | Jones | Greetings from Jones.
```

YMMV in MySQL, but I think the constructions above will work straight off.

(edit: Added INSERTs for clarification)

Comment: Wow.  It's really jargony.  Why did you use a # before SELECT, and why U.id AS user_id, and why is it acceptable to use U rather than users?  I thought that nicknames for tables had to be assigned prior to their use?

Comment: You can skip table aliases if you want, it's just a shorter way to write queries. If "posts.content" is easier to read than "P.content", feel free to skip aliases.

The "#" before SELECT was the prompt from Postgres's shell.

Answer (score 2):

The pretty much way is to add a user id in the post table. Insert user id which each post. Then by extracting the information use the simple join to get the complete information. You select query should looks like

```
 select post.content,post.date,users.firstname,user.lastname from post,users where post.userid=users.id
```

Comment: Awais Qarni, Thanks for the code.  Would I need to use a scripting language to handle the User ID assignment in the Posts table, or would MySQL do it?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Welcome dear. But I didn't understand what do you want to say?

Comment: `SELECT post.content, post.date, users.username FROM post, users WHERE post.userid = post.id ORDER BY post.date ASC` seems like what I'm trying to do.  When I type `INSERT INTO posts (content) VALUES ('In the old days, everybody wore hakama in Japan.  These days, only girls wear them, and typically only during graduation ceremonies.');`, `post.postID` is auto-incremented.  Would something like a session cookie handle `post.userID`?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 its totally upto you. You can store the user id in session like `$_SESSION['userid']=$userid`, then store this session in your query `where post.userid=$_SESSION['userid'];`

Answer (score 1):

[Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would suggest that the best method is "two tables with columns", relating user content to user via user_id. This method is known to manage both bears and goats more efficiently in the long-run.

Comment: Good stuff, neokio.  Thanks for the link.