# What is the permanence of references and joins in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, reference

What does 'joining' do?  I can't find any 'secondary key' in phpMyAdmin..., only primary keys.  Even though I often read about them in my books, they seem like to be instantiated or environmental, rather than permanent.  In other words, do 'joins' only exist in selects, or does the database structure itself change when there is a `JOIN` or a `REFERENCE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JOIN is an abstract method (i.e., it's nothing that **physically** exists in the database) that occurs only during the query in question (*no pun intended*).  JOIN is used in queries that span several tables that have references to each other.  *It is not necessary to have references for a JOIN to work.  What JOIN does is simply joins targeted tables, giving you a broader data set to select values from.

Common types of joins are INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and CROSS JOIN.  The one used in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845932/content-by-user-two-tables-with-columns-of-the-same-name-or-join/7845992#7845992) was a CROSS JOIN, although the keyword itself was left out.  That is: `SELECT A.name, B.name FROM table1 A, table2 B`--an implicit cross join.  `SELECT A.country, B.country FROM iteration1 A CROSS JOIN iteration2 B` is explicit.  It's just a matter of taste.

Generally, joins create large data sets, and you need to pinout your queries (using WHERE or similar) to extract the data you are looking for.

Comment: I like how you've assigned termonology to a definition I was seeking.  The JOIN hyponym gives me a more complete syntax for understanding JOIN.  Thanks for the follow-up, Boss.

Comment: I hope you can smile on the edit, bos.  I really want to pay it back.  You rock.  I've been looking for a clear answer to this question for such a long time, and thanks to you I finally have it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The joining is only related to a particular query and only persists for its execution.